# Symfony SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory database connection

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm working on MacOS using *MAMP* and trying to connect my Symfony framework with database. But I'm always getting these errors.

[image: console errors]

Here is my .env file:

```ini
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=dfa38e65f5a82a254945036ae326e50e
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^(localhost|example\.com)$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
 DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/test_project?serverVersion=5.7"
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
```

And here is my connection parameters:

```
Host        localhost
Port        8889
Username    root
Password    root
Socket      /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: When you launch MAMP, do you see two green dots in the upper right corner indicating that both Apache Server and MySQL Server are running? I will guess no...

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you're trying to connect to port `3306` whereas the MySQL instance is working on port `8889`.

The correct environment variable in the `.env` file is

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@localhost:8889/test_project?serverVersion=5.7"
```

In addition to that, you've to be sure that the `test_project` database exists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your "port" to "8889" and not use "3306".
you can config your database url to "`DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:8889/test_project`"